# check how many pages that you saw in my website. (PHP,cookie)

Tags: php, cookies

It's first time to use cookie.

I want to make a message that shows how many pages that you saw in my site.

Like "you saw (n)pages in my site."

so I made PHP code. but it has a problem.

```
<?php

setcookie("howMany", $value, time()+(60*60*365));
$value = $value + 1;

echo "you saw" + $value + "pages in my site";

?>
```

I refresh the page, but the number not changed.
which part is wrong?

Comment: Should probably add the path `'/'` to setcookie() as well so you don't get multiple cookies if the user visits different directories on the web site.  Otherwise, it will not add to this cookie if they went from /index.html to /folder/index.html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple mistake

***cookie*** should be set after you create `$value`, not before it. And you should pick up the count from cookies, not from your own page's internal variables

```
$value = $_COOKIE["howMany"] + 1;
setcookie("howMany", $value, time()+(60*60*365),'/');
echo "you saw " + $value + " pages on my site";
```

Comment: As I suggested above, adding a path (/) to the setcookie will be useful if pages are in different directories.

Comment: Thanks for the note. Answer updated as suggested to allow domain level cookies

Answer (score 0):

Your variable **value** is always NULL, so what you need is to get the cookie first, then increment it, and put the value back to cookie.